# Finding marked price

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A trader allows a trade discount $20\%$ and a cash discount of $6\frac14\%$ on the marked price of the goods and gets a net gain $20\%$ of the cost. By how much above the cost should the goods be marked for the sale? $40\%/50\%/60\%/70\%$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the marked price be $x$ and the cost price be $y$.

So, $x-0.2x-\frac{0.25}4x=1.2y\implies x=1.6y\implies$ marked price should be $60\%$ above the cost price.

Comment: add this to your question, and let the others first comment or answer

Comment: No, I am sharing it as Q&A format.